# CMake cant find installed Python Interpreter

Tags: python, cmake, gnu, ubuntu-20.04, uhd

My system is of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS having a python version 3.8.10. but while installing USRP open source tool chain UHD 3.14.0.0. there arises an error regarding python interpreter for cmake as follows

```
$ cmake ..
-

-- Configuring the python interpreter...
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.0")
-- Python interpreter: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
-- Override with: -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=<path-to-python>
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/UHDPython.cmake:54 (message):
Error: Python interpreter required by the build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/Modules/UHDVersion.cmake:9 (include)
cmake/Modules/UHDPackage.cmake:9 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:110 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/capsys/workarea/uhd/host/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

all the available python versions in my system as follows

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10`

$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3.8-config  /usr/bin/python3.8-dbg         /usr/bin/python3.8d-config  /usr/bin/python3d     /usr/bin/python3-dbg-config  /usr/bin/python3-futurize
/usr/bin/python3.8  /usr/bin/python3.8d        /usr/bin/python3.8-dbg-config  /usr/bin/python3-config     /usr/bin/python3-dbg  /usr/bin/python3d-config     /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
```

why cant cmake find the installed libraries? is there any specific cmd to make cmake look for specific python library for build?

Do I need to install any specific version of python for this ?

```
$ cmake ..
-

-- Configuring the python interpreter...
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.0")
-- Python interpreter: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
-- Override with: -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=<path-to-python>
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/UHDPython.cmake:54 (message):
Error: Python interpreter required by the build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/Modules/UHDVersion.cmake:9 (include)
cmake/Modules/UHDPackage.cmake:9 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:110 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/capsys/workarea/uhd/host/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: You can place code (or output) between a pair of triple backticks. I fixed the code boxes, please verify that I didn't change anything of their actual content. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to set the environment variable [PYTHON_EXECUTABLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html)? I'm guessing that from the error message you posted. A quick websearch `CMake PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` gave me the above link.